# I don't understand the logic of a working program class

Tags: c++

All, being brief as possible, I’m working on an exercise from C++ Primer Plus Sixth Ed. by Stephen Prata.  Chapt 10 Ex 6 for those playing along at home. I wasn’t sure what the exercise was asking. I found someone online who had done the exercises. I thought seeing the program in action, I’d understand the requirement and recreate my own.  The program I downloaded works perfectly.  My lack of understanding of why is works is my issue.  I’m hoping someone here can clear up what I’m not understanding.

```
MOVE.H

class Move{
private:
double x;
double y;
public:
Move(double a = 0, double b = 0); // sets x, y to a, b

void showmove() const;
Move add(const Move & m) const;
void reset(double a = 0, double b = 0); // resets x,y to a, b
};

MOVE.CPP (there are other class methods that deal with display and reset. I excluded them to conserve space.)
Move::Move(double a, double b)
{ x = a;  y = b;}
Move Move::add(const Move & m) const
{
double m_x, m_y;
m_x = this-\>x + m.x;
m_y = this-\>y + m.y;
Move newMove(m_x, m_y);
return newMove;
}

MAIN.CPP (There of other line items for display etc.)
Move move1;  //Nothing sent so defaults to (x=0,y=0)per the constructor
Move move2(1.5, 2.5); // constructor set move2 x =1.5 & y=2.5
Move move3(1.5, 2.1); // constructor set move3 x=1.5 & y=2.1
Move move4(move2.add(move3));  // this is where my confusion lies.
```

When creating move4, I expected the constructor to look for nothing being sent or a combination of 2 doubles.  Move2::add returns a reference or address of a newly created Move class called newMove. How does the constructor of move4 know to extract the x and y from newMove of class move2.
The program works as expected.  Move4 X=3 and Y=4.6. I’m obviously missing something.  One of the downsides to learning without a teacher / tutor. Thanks.

Comment: *"Move2::add returns a reference or address of a newly created Move class"* - no, it returns a new object. Not its address.

Comment: There is also a default copy constructor, which should have been mentioned in the book at that point. (That book's reputation isn't very good. Despite it's name, it is not an improved "C++ Primer".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the constructor of move4 know to extract the x and y from newMove of class move2.

Your class does not explicitly define or delete its [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor), and all of its fields can be copied, so you get a copy constructor for free. Effectively, you get a constructor that does

```
Move(const Move& that) : x(that.x), y(that.y) {}
```

but the compiler provides it for you.

You can always provide a `Move(const Move&)` function yourself which will replace the compiler-generated one. And if you don't want one at all (common in smart pointer types that uniquely own a resource), you can delete it

```
Move(const Move& that) = delete;
```